# Disable bounce between UIScrollView pages

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView with paging declared as follows:

```
    _scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
    _scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    _scrollView.bounces = NO;
```

It's important that when a user is swiping between pages, the scroll view deceleration does not bounce over into the next page, and comes to a complete stop.  Setting `_scrollView.bounces = NO;` only removes bouncing at the edges of the entire scrollview, not between pages themselves.  Any ideas?

Comment: Came across same issue, have you found a solution ?